# Docker: build with different results compared to manual step-by-step build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to build a docker image with a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN echo '91.189.88.161   archive.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts;
RUN echo '91.189.88.162   security.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts;
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git-core python-pip xvfb wkhtmltopdf python-setuptools python-dev build-essential imagemagick libjpeg-dev locales libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN pip install -r /home/user/requirements/homologacao.txt

CMD /bin/bash
```

but it does not work. After a few seconds it throws some errors in the 3rd step (apt-get update):

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

However ... if I manually create and attach to a container, using the following command

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04
```

And then run each command individually, it works like a charm! Can anyone explain to me why does this build do not work, and manually running the commands does? It looks like as each layer/command is not having any effect at all.

What should I do to get this automatic build working? I've changed `/etc/default/docker` to include the docker network interface in the DNS list:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --dns 172.17.0.1"
```

Some other info that may be help: Running in an ubuntu 16.04 host, and this issue doesn't happen inside a VM (also ubuntu 16.04) in the same machine. Inside the VM, the apt-get update works right out of the box without having to update /etc/hosts.

Comment: Not sure, but are the semi colons causing issues: RUN echo '91.189.88.161   archive.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts;
RUN echo '91.189.88.162   security.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts;

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but the result was the same.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is controlled by docker (it injects linking and local host information). So any changes to this file will be lost after the run command completes and you start a new run command. Jose's advice should correct your issue.

Comment: That info was very helpfull @BMitch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your `Dockerfile` and `apt-get update` worked perfectly.

Try the following steps:

1. Create or edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
2. Add the following content

> ```
> {
>   "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
> }
> ```

3. Restart Docker daemon: `sudo service docker restart`

Edit: Try this.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN echo '91.189.88.161   archive.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts && \
    echo '91.189.88.162   security.ubuntu.com' >> /etc/hosts && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git-core python-pip xvfb wkhtmltopdf python-setuptools python-dev build-essential imagemagick libjpeg-dev locales libpq-dev postgresql-client

RUN pip install -r /home/user/requirements/homologacao.txt

CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: The last command may need to be `systemctl restart docker` for systemd environments.

Comment: `service docker restart` works in the majority of the systems since it has an implementation to `systemctl` too.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JoséAntonioLópez, but that also did not work. Changed `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and `/etc/default/docker` to include 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 172.17.0.1 (docker network interface) and 143.54.188.1 (gateway on my company) and still doesn't work. It seem to be a DNS issue as ping with addresses fail, but ping IPs works. Funny fact is that inside a VM the problem does not occurs. Any other ideas?